# Finding width/height of element on Canvas without drawing it to the screen

Tags: android, canvas

I'm building an app that has to measure the font to figure out how many words can fit on a canvas, and then using that information to split the string into multiple parts. The way I am thinking about doing this is trying to write the font and string into some sort of Canvas buffer, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for, how to do it or if its even the best method (slow?). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: StaticLayout does not encompass the methods I need because it doesn't take height into consideration. I have tried using StaticLayout and then translating the canvas, but it tends to slice some of the lines since it doesn't know where the lines are!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Paint.measureText` methods and at the `Paint.FontMetrics` class.